# Custom interface TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would type to get custom TypeScript interface :

```
export type CreateActions<T> = T;
```

So I can do something like :

```
const actionCreators = {
  add: null,
  remove: null
}

const { creators }: { creators: CreateActions<ActionCreators> } = createActions('Jedi', actionCreators);

creators.add({ name: 'Yoda' });
```

So I want to get method "add" to be understood by TypeScript.

Thanks for your advice !

Here's the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20CreateActions%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ActionCreators%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20add%3A%20Function%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20remove%3A%20Function%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20method%20should%20not%20be%20changed.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Or%20maybe%20adding%20an%20output%20type%0D%0Aexport%20const%20createActions%20%3D%20(name%3A%20string%2C%20actions%3A%20Object)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20types%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20let%20creators%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20Object.keys(actions).forEach(actionKey%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20type%20%3D%20%60%24%7Bname.toUpperCase()%7D%2F%24%7BactionKey%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20types%5BactionKey.toUpperCase()%5D%20%3D%20type%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20creators%5BactionKey%5D%20%3D%20(payload%3A%20Object)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20types%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20creators%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ActionList%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bname%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Object%20%7C%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20think%20this%20one%20should%20not%20be%20changed%0D%0Aconst%20actionList%3A%20ActionList%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20add%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20remove%3A%20null%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20I%20absolutely%20don't%20know%20how%20type%20%22creators%22%20here%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20creators%20%7D%3A%20%7B%20creators%3A%20CreateActions%3CActionCreators%3E%20%7D%20%3D%20createActions('Jedi'%2C%20actionList)%3B%0D%0Acreators.add(%7B%20name%3A%20'Yoda'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

**EDIT** :

It's difficult to explain, I'm sorry.

What I want is : I have an object that have some keys. It's values are "null" or "object".

I want a method that takes those keys and generate methods for those.

So if I have

```
const myObject = {
  myKey: null,
  otherKey: null,
}
```

I want my method to output :

```
{
  myKey: () => ...,
  otherKey: () => ...
}
```

So, I want to add TypeScript validations based on my first object. This object (myObject in my case) is not known, and its keys may vary.

Comment: I really don't get what you're trying to achieve nor what's the obstacle you describe. Can you maybe make an understandable example in the TypeScript playground ? http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: @KewinDousse Thanks for your reply, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have functions in your `interface` properties, declare their type which is `Function`. Also if you don't know at compile time what keys they'll be placed at, then be aware that TypeScript will also only be able to help with as much info as you give him.

I see that in your example, you define these functions **after** the object is created, so you'll need to declare them as nullable, that means adding a `| null` meaning they can be `null` (as they are in their initial state).

Which makes the final code of your interface like this :

```
interface ActionCreators {
    [key: string]: Function | null
}
```

Here is the playground link of your case, with an example an error at the end when trying to assign something other than a function : [Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20type%20CreateActions%3CT%3E%20%3D%20T%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ActionCreators%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Function%20%7C%20null%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20createActions%20%3D%20(name%3A%20string%2C%20actions%3A%20Object)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20let%20types%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20let%20creators%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20Object.keys(actions).forEach(actionKey%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20type%20%3D%20%60%24%7Bname.toUpperCase()%7D%2F%24%7BactionKey%7D%60%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20types%5BactionKey.toUpperCase()%5D%20%3D%20type%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20creators%5BactionKey%5D%20%3D%20(payload%3A%20Object)%20%3D%3E%20(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20payload%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20types%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20creators%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20actionCreators%3A%20ActionCreators%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20add%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20remove%3A%20null%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20%7B%20creators%20%7D%3A%20%7B%20creators%3A%20CreateActions%3CActionCreators%3E%20%7D%20%3D%20createActions('Jedi'%2C%20actionCreators)%3B%0D%0Acreators.add(%7B%20name%3A%20'Yoda'%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Acreators.add%20%3D%204%3B)

Comment: That's not what I really want.

My object "actionCreators" is just an Object where its values ARE NOT functions. 

But CreateActions returns an object { creators } that will have the same keys than "actionCreators" but with functions generated. 

I'm sorry if I can't make me understandable :(

Comment: The naming of your variables and types is probably quite confusing. You're saying "CreateActions returns an object", but that's the name of the type you defined, not the function. If I try to recap, you want to initialize an Object which has properties, all of which are `null`, and then call a function on that Object so that is returns the same Object but with with each key filled with a function instead of `null`, is that correct ?

Comment: Or, maybe simpler to answer : In your Playground, which lines do you consider to be correct and shouldn't be changed, and which lines are you unsure of ?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope you will understand now. Thanks for your help !

Comment: I also edited my answer. Does it better reflect what you're trying to do or am I still off ?